# Promise callback on Jquery never runs when empty response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a POST service in backend which returns an empty response body.

I call the service with an ajax call from jquery like this which returns a promise:

```
return $.when($.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: (xhr) => {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    },
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true
}))
```

Then calling the method:

```
myMethod(params).done(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }
)
```

So the ajax call is made, however, the done is never runned.
If the server returns something in the response body it works.

Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: You don't need `$.when`. Just return `$.ajax(..)` itself.

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning a `fail()`? Maybe you want `.always()`?

Comment: hindmost I want a promise.

@Liam, could be failing, but done, is not the same as always?

Comment: No, nor am I saying that. But if you want it to trigger success or failure, then you want an always

Comment: @hindmost is right BTW, you don't need the `$.when`

Comment: `$.ajax` exactly returns a promise

Comment: `done` is the success case, `fail` is the error case, `always` triggers regardless

Comment: I though `then` was the success case

Comment: From jquery.com "`jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`
An alternative construct to the success callback option, refer to `deferred.done()` for implementation details."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery 1.9 treats json ajax requests with an empty result as a failure.

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

You should either handle this as a `fail` case, not use the `json` type, or fix your server to not send empty responses when json is requested.

Comment: which should be the type for this empty response?

Comment: If you control the server, I would change it to return `{}`. Otherwise, a `dataFilter` function on your ajax request that checks for an empty response and replaces it with `{}`?

Comment: I do not control it. I cannot change the dataType to `text` or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, you could; or probably even not set `dataType`; it will depend on what you plan to do with the response.

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions:**

1. Change the AJAX datatype to ‘Text’ - (even JSON response will be treated as Text).

   ```
   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: serviceURL,
   dataType: 'text'
   ```

   });
2. Do not provide any datatype attribute for $.ajax call. It will intelligently guess the output and do the conversion.

*https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - dataType*

> make sure that response header – “Content-Type” is text/plain and mimeType is not explicitly provided as part of AJAX options.

**ajaxHandleResponses** - will automatically try to detect the conversion type based on mimeType and Content-Type header.

```
function ajaxHandleResponses( s, jqXHR, responses ) {

var ct, type, finalDataType, firstDataType,
    contents = s.contents,
    dataTypes = s.dataTypes;

// Remove auto dataType and get content-type in the process
while ( dataTypes[ 0 ] === "*" ) {
    dataTypes.shift();
    if ( ct === undefined ) {
        ct = s.mimeType || jqXHR.getResponseHeader( "Content-Type" );
    }
}
```

3. Do AJAX custom conversion based on response either to JSON or retain as String if the response is not JSON.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceURL,
                converters: {
                    'text mycustomtype': (result) => {
                        return this.getResponse(result);
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'mycustomtype'
            });

        this.getResponse = (result) => {
            let response;
            try {
                response = JSON.parse(result);
            }
            catch (e) {
                response = result;
            }
            return response;
        };
```

4. Always pass the JSON response from the server. Either as empty JSON - {} or with an attribute result with empty data (**my preferred solution** *considering that majority of the response is going to be JSON*)

   {"result":""}